# The rules for manyshot/ rapid shot

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, ranged-attack

In our campaign another argument has arisen. A fighter has the feats rapid shot and manyshot but he is using a rapid reload crossbow. The problem is the GM is confused as to whether this is even possible. On the feat it says "arrow" the GM thinks that means it can work on a Regular rapid reload crossbow but the players dont think thats the case (and before anyone asks its the fighter USING it making the biggest argument against it being feasible) So does anyone know if you can use it with a crossbow and if so would you please write exactly HOW in your answer so that I many share it with the party? Thanks to all who help

Comment: Thank you all very much the players get it now ^^ this is exactly the explanation we needed and also thank you for the tips. They are very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Based on the [Lian Nu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Liannu.jpg), I'd be tempted to houserule that Manyshot could work with a repeating crossbow in 3.x.

Comment: On another note, could someone explain what a "rapid reload crossbow" is in 3.5?  Is it a misnamed repeating crossbow, an exotic item from an obscure book, or something else?

Comment: I'd really like this question to be rewritten because, at least I, required to look at an answer to understand the question. I'd do it myself but my DnD 3.5 knowledge is not as good as it used to be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rapid Reload feat says:

> If you have selected this feat for hand crossbow or light crossbow, you may **fire that weapon as many times** in a full attack action as you could attack if you were using a bow.

Rapid Shot feat says:

> You can get **one extra attack** per round with a ranged weapon. [...] You must use the full attack action to use this feat.

Manyshot feat says:

> As a standard action, you may fire two arrows at a single opponent within 30 feet. **Both arrows use the same attack roll**

Rapid Reload lets you fire a crossbow *as many times* as a bow. Rapid Shot lets you fire an extra time.

Manyshot doesn't affect the *number of times* you can fire, just *how many arrows* you can fire each time. Since it specifies arrows, it works for bows only. Rapid Reload doesn't change this.

Using common sense (which doesn't always apply in D&D, but anyway...) there is no way to load two bolts in a crossbow at once. The bolt sits in a groove; the string is drawn back to a single point. While it may be possible to design a crossbow to fire more than one bolt at once, a standard one is not physically capable of it.

(Also worth noting, in case there was any confusion, you can't combine Rapid Shot and Manyshot in the same action - Rapid Shot uses a full attack action, Manyshot uses a standard action.)

Answer (score 6):

Bows fire [arrows](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Arrows), crossbows fire [bolts](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Crossbow_Bolts).  You can't use [manyshot](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Manyshot) with a crossbow, though [rapid shot](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Rapid_Shot) works just fine.